# Why a asp:DropDownList and a asp:TextBox of the same width appear differently

Tags: c#, html

I am using the below code inside of a table:

```
<tr>
    <td>User Language:</td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Language" runat="server" Width="200px">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">English</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span class="important">*</span>Company:</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="Company" runat="server" width="200px" /></td>
</tr>
```

When the code appears on the site the `<asp:Textbox>` control is 205px and the `<asp:DropDownList>` is 200px wide.  What is causing that?  They both are set to a width of 200px.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because the textbox has 2px of border and 1px of padding on the sides.

Comment: Pardon me, I use Google Chrome (version: 59.0.3071.86). When I inspect the page, it says the width of textbox is **4px** more (204px) than that of DropDownList (200px). (So even 2px + 1px is 3px, still 1px short!)

Answer (score 1):

The DropDown is resized regarding the size of the options you provide in it. So, If you have longer options, you will get longer drop down. In addition it takes more place for the arrow that is the right corner.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite related, but here's a quick tip that will save you a lot of headache down the road:

**Never use ASP:Textbox or ASP:DropDownList**

<textbox runat=server> and <select runat=server> will work in every single case you could ever need, and they don't add any confusing properties such as "width" that don't quite work right.

Use real HTML tags with CSS classes for everything you do, and only add runat=server to the ones you actually intend to mess with from the backend.

Comment: Is this good advice? There must be some reason these controls exist. Can you databind HTML textboxes and dropdownlists?

Comment: They exist partly for consistency, but primarily to support the early ASP.NET idea of drag & drop web forms.  People wisely avoid drag & dropping their way to unmaintainable code, but they sometimes forget that every HTML tag supports runat=server and therefore they don't need to use the asp: equivilants.

Comment: Yes, in answer to your question, you'll find that HtmlSelect has a .DataSource property and a .DataBind() method, as well as Text and Value members.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert data in the dropdownlist it resizes if you do not set the width property, but if you set the width it will not resize.